# qmail smtpd uptime less then 1 sec

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, email, email-server

not sure what is going on here but my qmail install isnt working corretly everything is running except smtpd

output from qmailctl stat

```
/service/qmail-send: up (pid 2874) 608 seconds
/service/qmail-send/log: up (pid 2876) 608 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd: up (pid 6486) 1 seconds
/service/qmail-smtpd/log: up (pid 2873) 608 seconds
messages in queue: 6
messages in queue but not yet preprocessed: 0
```

netstat -a | grep smtp returns noting, so nothing is running on smtp

and the inst_check script returns

```
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
Congratulations, your LWQ installation looks good!
```

iv gone throught the tutorial fond here http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#installation
3 times and the 2.8.2.2. The supervise scripts like 8 times and everything is right as far as i can tell

any help would be great! need to get this runnin asap!

EDIT:
also i have noticed that every time i restart the server i must run

```
svscanboot &
```

before starting qmail not sure why everything was installed right, although i did have to do the ./config-fast to configure not sure if that makes a difference but FYI i suppose :)

Comment: why is the post a -1 now?

Comment: still ahve not figured this out really could use some help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Your service is not starting properly.  Read its log and test the script.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/daemontools-service-not-staying-up.html)  Follow the suggestions for common errors.